# What does $\sigma(v(t))$ in a Langevin equation refer to?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, expected-value, stochastic-differential-equations

I am having a problem with this form of Langevin equation:

$m d v(t)=-k v(t) d t+\sigma(v(t)) d W(t) \quad \cdots (1)$

where:

- $v(t)$ velocity of the particle
- $m$ mass of the particle
- $k$ coefficient of friction  (that according to my lecture is supposed to be equal to $6 \pi \eta a$ , where :

  - $a$ : radius of the particle
  - $\eta$ : viscosity of the solvent
- $-k v(t)$ friction force
- $W$ Wiener process
- $\sigma$ variations amplitude (?)

By comparing it to a Langevin equation on a lecture :

$m \frac{d v(t)}{d t}=-k v(t)+\mathbf{F}(t)$  ​

Where is the random force with the properties :

$\begin{array}{c}
\langle\mathbf{F}(t)\rangle=\mathbf{0} \\
\langle\mathbf{F}(t) \mathbf{F}(0)\rangle=2 k_{B} T k \mathbf{I} \delta(t)
\end{array}$

By identification I get $\sigma(v(t)) \frac{d W(t)}{dt}= F(t)$  is the random force?

Later in the lecture in a section for numerical analysis, we define a new random variable called the Wiener process :

$\int_{t_{i}}^{t_{4+1}}  \mathbf{F}(t)d t \equiv \Delta \mathbf{W}_{i}$

where :

$\left\langle\Delta \mathbf{W}_{i}\right\rangle=0 \\
\left\langle\Delta \mathbf{W}_{i} \Delta \mathbf{W}_{j}\right\rangle=2 k_{B} T k \Delta t \mathrm{I} \delta_{i j}$

where :

- $I$  : is the unit tensor
- The prefactor $2k_BTk$ is determined to satisfy the fluctuation-dissipation theorem
- The angular parentheses note the average 'expectation'

but then aren't we approximating

$\frac{d W(t)}{dt} \simeq F(t)$ ( my lecture said the random force $F$ is not continuous but we assume its integral is, 'for which we introduce the new random variable $\Delta W_i$')

If so, what is the $\sigma(v(t)) $ ?

I can't see what does the $\sigma(v(t))$ mean in the equation $(1)$ and where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first equation just shows a general version of a Langevin equation. In principle, you can make the noise term as complicated as you want. For example, if we would take $F(t,v)=vdW(t)$, then we would have $\sigma(v)=v$. However, in this case, your lecturer assumed that $F$ does not depend on $v$ and hence $\sigma$ is constant. At this point, you can choose what to do with $\sigma$. In this case $W(t)$ is defined as a Brownian motion with variance $2k_BTkI$ and $\sigma=I$. However, you could also have chosen to define $W(t)$ to be a 'standard' Brownian motion, i.e. with variance $I$. In that case, you can choose $\sigma=\sqrt{2k_B TkI}$. As you can see now by the notation, $\sigma$ informally represents the standard deviation of your noise term $F$.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please refer me to some source that states this please?

Comment: Or that shows the cases where we want to make that term complicated?

Comment: Many of the basics are explained on the wiki-page on Langevin equations. However, it is important to realize that Langevin Equations are only `heuristic', in the sense that there is no real underlying theory. In order to understand terms like $vdW(t)$ you need a proper understanding of stochastic differential equations, i.e. you need Ito or Stratonovich calculus. Anyway, the most basic example of such an equation is the Geometric Brownian motion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion